# PHP MySQL appending contents of one field to contents of another

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that has the fields `product_category` and `product_name`. I want to append the `product_category` to the front of the `product_name` and update for a specific `product_category`.

How do I do this? I realized after entering hundreds of records that the `product_category` is part of the `product_name`.

Comment: You can do it but you shouldn't because if you want to avoid trouble in the future your data should stay as atomic as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)  that concatenates strings, skipping null values, with a separator, and this could be your update query:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET product_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', product_category, product_name)
WHERE product_category = 'category'
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be easy. That worked very well. I am a relative beginner and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You would run:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET product_name = product_category.' '.product_name WHERE product_category = ?
```

Comment: i think the concat operator in sql is ||

Comment: @DavidChan: By default, `||` is logical `OR` in MySQL unless the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) SQL mode is enabled (in which case, as you say, it's string concatenation).  The [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function is string concatenation in MySQL under every circumstance.